# jquery slide - slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

im working on my fixed-footer on my page
I have three `DIV`'s. The first one which is on the left side holds some items and the other `DIV` which is on the right side is a relative div. Between these `DIV`'s is another `DIV` which is named controller. When I click on the controller the left `DIV` should slide to the left side an disapear like `slideToggle()` but the controller and the right `DIV` should stick to the left slided `DIV`. And if I click on the controller again when the left `DIV` is not longer displayed it should slide to the right and the controller and the right `DIV` should have the same slide effect. The controller `DIV` and the right `DIV` is always displayed!

Here a fiddle example I build:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ydy0o95/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, slideToggle doesn't exactly fit here as it toggles dispay, while in your description you rather need toggling a width of the left div - from 400px to 0 and back. https://jsfiddle.net/6ydy0o95/2/

The main difficulties in your example I found is to make the audio  to stretch the whole resting space when the left div#bar is on and off. For that i leave #audio without any position specifications - no floats, display, width are predefined. #bar and #controller are set a definite width and float:left;

```
#bar {
     width:400px;
     float:left;
}

#controller {
     float:left;
     width:20px;
 }
```

Hope, that'll do what you need.

Comment: looks great :) will test it on my webpage and will you know if this work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can animate some what like this. I have prepared a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ydy0o95/3/) . I have done for only 1st div... same you can apply whereever you want

```
$(".bar_item").click(function(){
if($(".bar_item").css('margin-left') === "0px")
{

   $(".bar_item").animate({"margin-left": '-=190'});
}
else
{

$(".bar_item").animate({"margin-left": '+=190'});
}


});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ydy0o95/3/)

Comment: @Selfproblemmade :did this helped you?